# Search and replace file names according to strings in dataframe. In R

Tags: r

I have several files in a folder that look like  "blabla_A1_bla.txt", "blabla_A1_bla.phd","blabla_B1_bla.txt", "blablabla_B1_bla.phd"...and all the way to H12.
Then I have a df that indicates which sample is each one.

| well | sample |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | F32-1 |
| B1 | F13-3 |
| C1 | B11-4 |
| ... | ... |

I want to rename the files in the folder according to the table. So that A1 gets replaces by F32-1, B1 by F13-3 and so on.

I have created a list of all the files in the directory with files<-list.files(directory). I know how to use the str_replace function of the stringr package to change them one by one, but I don't know how to make it automatic. I guess I need a loop that reads cell 1,1 of the dataframe, searches that string in "files" and replaces it with the value in  cell 1,2. And then moves to cell 2,1 and so on. But I don't know how to code this. (Or if there is a better way to do it).

I'll appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a named vector of replacement and pattern and use it in `str_replace_all`

```
files <- list.files(directory)
files <- stringr::str_replace_all(files, setNames(df$sample, df$well))
```

---

Using a reproducible example -

```
df <- structure(list(well = c("A1", "B1", "C1"), sample = c("F32-1", 
"F13-3", "B11-4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

files <- c("blabla_A1_bla.txt", "blabla_A1_bla.phd","blabla_B1_bla.txt", "blablabla_B1_bla.phd")

stringr::str_replace_all(files, setNames(df$sample, df$well))
#[1] "blabla_F32-1_bla.txt"    "blabla_F32-1_bla.phd"    "blabla_F13-3_bla.txt"   
#[4] "blablabla_F13-3_bla.phd"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to coerce df$well and df$sample as characters for it to work, but then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a vector of new names and then use the function `file.rename`:

```
files = c("blabla_A1_bla.phd","blabla_B1_bla.txt", "blablabla_B1_bla.phd")
patterns = c('A1', 'B1')
replace = c('F22', 'G22')


new.name = c()
for (f in files){
  # first identify which pattern corresponds to file f (sis it A1, B1, ...)
  which.pattern = which(sapply(patterns, grepl, x = f))
  # and then replace it by the correct string
  new.name = c(new.name, gsub(patterns[which.pattern], replace[which.pattern], f))
}
file.rename(files, new.name)
```

replacing `patterns` and `replace` by `df$well` and `df$sample` should work for your case.

Comment: It says "invalidad "from" argument". Also, with file.rename I need to say exactly the file name, it doesn't let me (or I don't know how to) search a part of the name. For example, If I write file.rename("A1", "F32-1") it gives me False, I have to say file.rename("blablabla_A1_bla.phd","F32-1.phd").

Comment: Yes, I realised that I not properly understood your issue at first. I edited my response accordingly. However, the use of str_replace_all by @ronak Shah seems to lead to a much easier solution.